# How can I hide certain submenus of the Settings tab in the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

I'd like to hide certain menus like Media, Privacy, and Permalinks. I've been using the following code to hide entire parent menus but not sure how to go about for submenus.

```
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
        $restricted = array(__('Links'), __('Comments'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'));
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to code it yourself, here is a good tutorial for customizing the Admin Menu. http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-wordpress-admin-area/

Copying from the tutorial, they remove the Editor sublink:

```
function remove_editor_menu() {
    remove_action('admin_menu', '_add_themes_utility_last', 101);
}
add_action('_admin_menu', 'remove_editor_menu', 1);
```

*note: you need to know the function / action that displays it*

Comment: Thank you. I was looking through tutorials but the one you linked had the most information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for that, it's called: Admin Menu Editor and you can download it here - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/ it is amazing. You can show and hide sub sections of menus and whole menus in the Wordpress admin, I use it all of the time to stop clients being able to change certain things and break the site.

Comment: Thank you, Dwayne. That looks like an awesome plugin but I just need a quick no-plugin method for this one. I'll probably use that plugin sometime in the future.